# Get unique value combinations with summary count of another variable

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr, summary

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
pred1 pred2 pred3 exp
a     b     c     0
a     d     c     0
a     b     c     1
```

What I would like to do is to first get all unique combinations of pred1-3, write them to an additional table, add a column for the frequency of each combination, and add another column that gives the proportion of the value 1 of exp (which can only be 0 or 1) for each combination. Something like this:

```
pred1 pred2 pred3 freq exp_prop
a     b     c     2    0.5
a     d     c     1    0
```

The first three steps turned out to be really easy with plyr:

```
ddply(df, .(pred1, pred2, pred3), summarise, freq=length(exp))
```

or shorter

```
count(df[,c(pred1, pred2, pred3)])
```

But I just can't figure out how to get the proportions of exp in.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost done. Just add `exp_prop = mean(exp)` to the `ddply` command:

```
ddply(df, .(pred1, pred2, pred3), summarise,
      freq = length(exp), exp_prop = mean(exp))

  pred1 pred2 pred3 freq exp_prop
1     a     b     c    2      0.5
2     a     d     c    1      0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# read in your data
x <- 
read.table(text="pred1 pred2 pred3 exp
a     b     c     0
a     d     c     0
a     b     c     1" , h = T)

library(sqldf)
sqldf( "select pred1, pred2, pred3, count(*) as numtimes, avg( exp ) as prop from x group by pred1, pred2, pred3" )

###### alternative:

# write all the column names according to some pattern
cols <- paste0("pred" , 1:3 , collapse = "," )

# save your data frame to another object
y <-
    sqldf( 
        paste( 
            "select" , 
            cols  , 
            " , count(*) as numtimes, avg( exp ) as prop from x group by" , 
            cols 
        ) 
    )

# print to screen
y
```

Comment: Hey, that was quick - many thanks! Unfortunately the sqldf package doesn't seem to be running on my computer. Loading it works, but as soon as I enter any command after that I get a message saying "caught bus error" and R crashes. Isn't there maybe a way to do this with native R syntax?

Comment: assume you're using mac?  install this and it will work.  sqldf is an amazing package.  http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/sqldf-hanging-on-macintosh-works-on-windows-tp3022193p3022397.html